# regex match nothing at the end of string

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to match any number of the literal # symbol separated by dots in a file name. The literal # symbol must be separated on either side by a dot EXCEPT in cases where it is the last element of a file name. I can create a pattern that does the first (matches any literal # symbols surrounded by dots) but I can't do it while also allowing the second (a file name that ends with a literal # symbol and no trailing dot).

For example, the following would match:

```
bob.#
bob.#.
bob.#.exr
bob.##.mary.tif
bob.####.png
```

Whereas the following would not match:

```
bob.#string.exr
bob.string#.exr
```

My pattern so far (expressed as a raw string in python) is:

```
(.*)(\.#+)((?:\.+.*|$))
```

Unfortunately it does not match the first item in my list: bob.#

I would have thought that the last, non-capturing group would basically read as:

match a literal dot followed by 0 or more characters

OR

match the end of the string

But testing it out in regexr.com shows it not matching bob.#

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression seems to be working just fine, I'd still modify that to some expression maybe similar to:

```
import re

regex = r"^([^.]*)(\.#+)(\..*)?$"

test_str ="""
bob.#
bob.#.
bob.#.exr
bob.##.mary.tif
bob.####.png
Whereas the following would not match:

bob.#string.exr
bob.string#.exr

"""

print(re.findall(regex, test_str,re.M))
```

#### Output

```
[('\nbob', '.#', ''), ('bob', '.#', '.'), ('bob', '.#', '.exr'), ('bob', '.##', '.mary.tif'), ('bob', '.####', '.png')]
```

---

> If you wish to explore/simplify/modify the expression, it's been
>   explained on the top right panel of
>   [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/MFkAGk/1/). If you'd like, you
>   can also watch in [this
>   link](https://regex101.com/r/MFkAGk/1/debugger), how it would match
>   against some sample inputs.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: Well now. I feel a bit the fool now. I am used to first trying out my regex in regexr.com and getting them honed there before transferring them into my code. Looks like that pattern may have failed me this time. Thanks! Edit: Looks like regexr likes your improved pattern.

Answer (score 2):

`^\w*?\.(#+)(\.\w*?)*?$`

This regex matches any number of word characters (including none) in front of one dot, matches one or more octothorpe symbols, and then optionally matches a dot and more words/chars.

```regex
^\w*?\.(#+)(\.\w*?)*?$

^                         anchor to the start of the line
 \w*?                     get as many word characters as you want, but as few as you need
     \.                   match . literally
       (#+)               match one or more # literally. grouped for your convenience if you want to count how many times they appear or something.
           (      )*?     match zero or more of this group:
            \.            a literal dot...
              \w*?        ...and zero or more word characters, as few as needed.
                     $    ensure the string ends with this group.
```

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/hmu4V3/1/)

A few notes about this regex:

- It will only match your string if there are no other strings on the line.
- The octothorpes are grouped and can be extracted later for counting (or whatever you want).
- `\w*` is generally both safer and faster than `.*` - it specifically looks for word characters `a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _` instead of ANY symbol. As a general rule, if you can make your regex more specific, you should, lest you risk the terrors of [catastrophic backtracking!](https://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html)

Comment: Thanks for the super clear explanation and breakdown! It is good to know about how \w works with regard to speed. In my particular case I need to match any character that might appear in a file name, including some pretty esoteric ones, but your warning (and link) are greatly appreciated.

Comment: You don't have to make the `\w*?` non greedy as it can not cross the dot and you don't have to make the last iteration of the group `*?$` non greedy as you are asserting the end of the string.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Solid advice - when I cut down on non-greediness, it saved 39 steps, too. I'll keep that in mind when I'm making future regexes.

Answer (score 1):

here's one if you want it to match the entire meta sequence:

```
import re

pattern = re.compile(r'(\w+\.\#+(?:\.|$)\w*\.*\w*)')
test = ['bob.#', 'bob.#.', 'bob.#.exr', 'bob.##.mary.tif', 'bob.####.png', 'bob.#string.exr', 'bob.string#.exr']
for t in test:
    print(re.findall(pattern, t))
```

output:

```
['bob.#']
['bob.#.']
['bob.#.exr']
['bob.##.mary.tif']
['bob.####.png']
[]
[]
```